# a sum() function with aritmatich 4 table

Tags: mysql, sql

this is sample data in table pengiriman_supply.
[image]
and this is for data_barang

[image]

this is for data_supplier and table masuk.

[image]
[image]

if I'm not using 3 tables the sum is no a problem but if I'm using 4 tables and using subtraction with `(sum(table1.a)-ifnull(table2.b))`. here is the result with just `sum` [image: with just sum]

and this is the picture with subtraction

[image]

the code is like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
row_number() over(
order by pengiriman_supply.po_nomor desc) as no,
pengiriman_supply.po_nomor as PO,
data_supplier.nama_supplier,
    data_barang.nama_barang,
    ((sum( pengiriman_supply.jumlah ))- (sum( COALESCE ( masuk.terima, 0 )) over ( PARTITION BY masuk.refrence ))) as total

FROM
    pengiriman_supply
    LEFT JOIN masuk ON pengiriman_supply.po_nomor = masuk.refrence
    INNER JOIN data_supplier ON data_supplier.id_supplier = pengiriman_supply.idsupplier
    INNER JOIN data_barang ON data_barang.idbarang = pengiriman_supply.idbarang
WHERE   
    pengiriman_supply.tanggal between date_sub(curdate(), interval 60 day) and curdate()
GROUP BY
pengiriman_supply.po_nomor,masuk.po_nomor,data_supplier.nama_supplier

ORDER BY
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT   pengiriman_supply.po_nomor) DESC
```

this the code that SQL statement that I can find. but the group by not make the SQL statement just `pengiriman_supply.po_nomor`. can I make the group by just the `pengiriman_supply.po_nomor` .[image]

can the number 31194 make in one group?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as pictures.

Comment: maybe the data in "masuk.terima" is not what you think it is, you are the only one that could tell as you didn't provide the input data

Comment: but I'm joining that with the 'masuk.refrence'  = 'pengiriman_supply.po_nomor',after that the result of the sum not the same as the table.

Answer (score 3):

it seems you need to include `ifnull(masuk.terima,0)` inside `sum()`

```
SELECT
pengiriman_supply.po_nomor AS po,
data_supplier.nama_supplier,
data_barang.nama_barang,
Sum((pengiriman_supply.jumlah)-ifnull(masuk.terima,0)) as total
FROM
pengiriman_supply
INNER JOIN data_barang ON pengiriman_supply.idbarang = data_barang.idbarang
INNER JOIN data_supplier ON pengiriman_supply.idsupplier = data_supplier.id_supplier
LEFT JOIN masuk ON masuk.refrence = pengiriman_supply.po_nomor
GROUP BY
pengiriman_supply.po_nomor
ORDER BY
po DESC
```